# Center content in grid with fixed height

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

on https://cdn02.plentymarkets.com/i3n17mn9ei6m/frontend/School-Mood/redesign09_2019/timeless-air/school-mood-timeless-air-dev.html I would like to vertically center the text in the upper left tile.

I used this code:

```
    <div class="row row-flex">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="shadow_box" style="height:456.891px;">
          <h2 class="text-center">Komplett</h2>
          <p>Mit dem 7-teiligen Set, bestehend aus Ranzen, Turnbeutel, gefülltem Etui, Schlamperrolle, Brustbeutel, Brotdose und Patchy-Set seid ihr bestens ausgestattet für den Schulalltag.</p>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="shadow_box" style="padding:0!important;">
   <img src="https://cdn02.plentymarkets.com/i3n17mn9ei6m/frontend/School-Mood/redesign09_2019/timeless-air/Komplett_Tair.jpg" style="max-width:100%;" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have set the div to exactly the height of the image so the left and right tile match in height.

How can i vertically center the entire text in the left tile? I can't seem to find out.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have to add this to your CSS to your shadow_box container

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
align-items: center; /*
```

[How Do I Vertically Center Text with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-do-i-vertically-center-text-with-css)

[Vertical and Horizontal Centering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically)